# Regex. Как выделить несколько строк?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как выделить несколько строк регулярным выражением.

Например

```
start
Sample text 1!
...Sample text 2?
!, Sample text 3
&Sample text 4&
...
end
```

https://regex101.com/r/0NtQ2z/1

Нужен текст между start и end.

Я могу сделать так

```
(start\n)+(.*\n+.*\n+.*\n+.*\n+.*\n)+(end)
```

Нужный мне текст будет во второй группе. Работает для 5 строк. Но ведь количество строк может быть больше или меньше.

Как написать регулярку для текста с любым количеством строк?

Comment: Попробуйте [таким образом](https://regex101.com/r/q1InCq/1) - `(?<=start\n)(.+\n)+(?=end)`

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо.  (?<=) (?=) Как эта конструкция называется?

Если будут два разных сегмента, то как в это условие добавить оператор ИЛИ?
https://regex101.com/r/DtTrxF/1

Comment: Это "Опережающие и ретроспективные проверки"  - https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind